# API with SLIM PHP in LAMP Server with MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, api, lamp, slim

I have Lamp server in my Ubuntu. I worked on Api's using slim framework and with mysql database and its working fine. My problem is I cant connect my api to MSSQL. 
I already install freetds in ubuntu
I also include this in freetds.conf

```
 [myserver]
    host = myhost
    port = myport
```

here's my connection:

```
function getConnection() {
   $dbhost="myserver.database.windows.net";
   $dbuser="user";
   $dbpass="mypass";
   $dbname="myDB";
   $dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   return $dbh;
}
```

here's my api in slim:

```
$app = new Slim\App();

$app->get('/clients', 'getClients'); 

$app->run();

function getClients() {
$sql = "select * FROM mytable";

try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
    $clients = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo '{"client": ' . json_encode($clients) . '}';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something....

I think you need to let PDO know what port

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

```
$hostname = "myhost";
$port = 10060;
$dbname = "tempdb";
$username = "dbuser";
$pw = "password";
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```